# android: app stops and then crashes when the screen goes off

Tags: android

The app runs perfectly fine, but when the screen goes off in my smartphone after a while of inactivity, the app just stops running. And when I press the button to go back to the main menu of the phone it just crashes (it stops).

What I would like if for the screen not to go off, or the app to continue running, or it would be fine if the app just exited when the screen goes off. I just don't know how.

Thanks very much.

The logcat

```
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111): Process: com.IceDriftGFS.icedrift, PID: 1111
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.IceDriftGFS.icedrift/com.IceDriftGFS.icedrift.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.lang.Thread.join()' on a null object reference
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3225)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3184)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3159)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.lang.Thread.join()' on a null object reference
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at com.IceDriftGFS.icedrift.Main$Run.pause(Main.java:114)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at com.IceDriftGFS.icedrift.Main.onPause(Main.java:54)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:6044)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1294)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3211)
12-14 21:47:07.526: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     ... 11 more
```

Code:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility") 
public class Main extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    Run run;
    static float Xpos, Yinc;
    static boolean actionDown = false;
    static int x, y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        run = new Run(this);
        run.setOnTouchListener(this);               
        setContentView(run);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        run.resume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        run.pause();
    }

public class Run extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    Canvas canvas;
    Thread thread = null;
    boolean isRunning = true;

    DisplayMetrics display;

    Player player;
    Background background;
    Walls walls;


    boolean plusCount = false;

    public Run(Context context) {
        super(context);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

        display = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        if(display.widthPixels > display.heightPixels){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Your device is not compatible with this game", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        player = new Player(context, display.widthPixels, display.heightPixels);
        background = new Background(context, display.widthPixels, display.heightPixels);
        walls = new Walls(context, display.widthPixels, display.heightPixels);


        Xpos = display.widthPixels - display.widthPixels/6;

        Yinc = display.heightPixels/280;
    }   

    public void pause(){
        isRunning = false;
        while(true){
            try{
                thread.join();
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        thread = null;
    }   

    public void resume(){
        isRunning = true;
    }   

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isRunning){   
            if(!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) 16.6666666667);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            background.run(canvas, Yinc);
            player.run(canvas, Xpos, actionDown);
            walls.run(canvas, Yinc);



            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);          
        }
    }



}

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();

        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                actionDown = true;
                Xpos = event.getX();    
            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                actionDown = false;
            break;
        }   
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the log comments to fix the issue. We cannot imagine what you have coded :)

Comment: This is because there is a fault in your code. We Need to see your logcat to fix the Problem with you. Everything else is just a Workaround( like preventing Screen from turning off when your app is at the front).. by the way, users don't like permissions...

Comment: Can you please post the code of the activity that crashes and maybe the error form the `logcat`?

Comment: Which line is 114 in your code? Post this line

Comment: @Gonzalo You got a NPE at line 114! There you got it run with the LogCat of your real device ;)

Comment: It worked, I had some useless code, I just deleted it. Thanks very much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make the screen always on you can lock him.
put that in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

this will prevent the screen to go off.

about the error, can you let us see the logCat and we will be able to see the error or the code and we will be able to understand whan happens.

Edit: now that we can see the code and error we can see the you have got NullPointerException.
I think you should add if(thread! = null) and the thrad.join() will be inside of him.
Please let me know if it works :)

Comment: Thanks very much. Do I need to ask permission to the users to use that?

Comment: well, when the user install the app it iwll show him that you are asking this permission. if he will install it the app stays open without asking

Comment: @Gonzalo the permission alone won't help. You still need to use a [`Wakelock`](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) to actually keep the screen alive.

Comment: Why? This is just a Workaround of his real Problem. The core Problem stays and sooner or later he will Need to face the real Problem.. @Gonzalo

Comment: @Mike I can't solve the actual problem if he doesn't post the logcat or the code. Also, he asked for the screen awake feature seperately, maybe he wants to implement it anyway.

Comment: @Mike he asked how to do it. without his code/ errors we cant help much

Comment: @Gumbo i know gumbo, that's why i would not post an answere with a workaround until he doesn't provide the informations we Need..

Comment: @amit farag `What I would like if for the screen not to go off, or the app to continue running, or it would be fine if the app just exited when the screen goes off. I just don't know how.` sounds more to me that he only asked for it that his error doesn't occur anymore. but that's just my opinion. happy coding ;)

Comment: It still goes off. I'm not working with the UI thread, it's a real time game that implements runnable. I can't see the logcat because the simulator's screen doesn't go off, it's just my phone that does so.

Comment: @Gonzalo LogCat also works with your real device... Load the app on you device, recreate the error and the logcat Output should automatically appear in you eclipse `logcat` window. just don't unplug your device during recreation of the Problem...

Comment: I just posted the logcat, :)

Comment: @Gonzalo there you got it! you got a NPE here: `at com.IceDriftGFS.icedrift.Main$Run.pause(Main.java:114)` got to your code and look why you get a NPE there. And also post your code to get better Support!